# Python nested dictionary with SQL insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have generated a very large dictionary after processing an XML file, and I am looking extract from this dictionary and to insert columns and values into my mySQL database table.

I am using Python 3.

The dictionary is nested; here's a simplistic example of what I have:

```
d ={'Test1'{'TestID':'first','Dev_Type':'this device','Version':'v1_0','Address':'some Address'}
    'Test2'{'TestID':'second','Dev_Type':'that device','Version':'v1_0','Address':'other Address'}
    'Test3'{'TestID','third','Dev_Type':'other device','Version':'v1_0','Address':'another Address'}
}
```

Essentially I want to iterate over each primary Key in this dictionary (e.g. Test1,Test2,Test3) and extract the secondary keys as a column name tuple and the associated seconday key values as a values tuple, a bit like this:

```
cols = ('TestID','Dev_Type','Version','Address')
vals = ('first','this device','v1_0','some Address')
```

On iterating over each primary key I will add the two tuples to my mySQL table using this command:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Parameters ({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(', '.join(cols), ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));
try:
    cursor.execute(sql, vals)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

Then repeat the process on the next primary key ('Test2').

I have made an initial attempt, but have hard coded the Primary key in this instance:

```
for k, v in d:
    #Missing appropriate method here
    cols = tuple(d['Test1'].keys())
    vals = tuple(d['Test1'].values())

    sql = "INSERT INTO Parameters ({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(', '.join(cols), ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
    except Exception as e:
        pass

connection.close()
return
```

Comment: This is tangential, but you should use the database API's parameter substitution to guard against SQL injections: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

Comment: Did you mean to leave out the `:` between the keys and values in your example dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `d.values()` and use the `.keys()` and `.values()` methods on the nested dictionaries to get the columns and values:

```
for v in d.values():
    cols = v.keys()
    vals = v.values()

    sql = "INSERT INTO Parameters ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
        ', '.join(cols),
        ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Note that in Python 3 [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) and [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) return *views* of the dictionary’s keys and values (unlike lists in Python 2).

Comment: Is there any guarantee that `v.values()` will always come in the same order as the list of keys `list(v)`? Else, you'll be inserting the wrong values in mismatching columns

Comment: There [is](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) such guarantee for `d.keys()` and `d.values()`. There's no mention of `list(d)` though.

Comment: Yep, that looks better

Comment: You can do `len(v)` instead of needlessly converting `cols` to a list.

Comment: Good call. I did not realize that the `keys` and `values` iterators actually define a length until now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @eugene y thanks for your help, this worked excellently. Very greatful!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a dictionary actually iterates over the keys. `for k in d:` is equivalent to `for k in d.keys():`. You are looking for the `values` or `items` methods, which will actually return the key and the value as a tuple:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    # k will take the values 'Test1', 'Test2', etc.
    # v will take the values of the corresponding nested dicts.
```

or

```
for v in d.values():
    # v will take on the values of the nested dicts.
```

I would recommend using `items` over `values` since that way you will have a reference to which primary key (test) you are processing. I am going to go out on a limb here and guess that you will need this for the non-trivial version of your program.

From there, you use `v` as you are trying to use `d[...]`, since that is exactly what it is:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    cols = v.keys()
    vals = v.values()

    sql = "INSERT INTO Parameters ({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(
                ', '.join(cols),
                ', '.join(['%s'] * len(v))
    )

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, vals)
    except Exception as e:
        pass

connection.close()
return
```

Since `v` is a nested dictionary, you can get the number of elements in both `cols` and `vals` as just `len(v)`.