# Write nested Python dictionary into SQL table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I have made some mistake in creating new table in SQL by mentioning its column also. Could anyone please review the code let me know your thoughts on this

```
db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    database = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00"
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Details ( User_ID VARCHAR(255), Name VARCHAR(255), Age VARCHAR(255), Occupation VARCHAR(255), Department VARCHAR(255), Salary VARCHAR(255), Address VARCHAR(255) ) ")
```

I need to write a nested Python dictionary into a SQL table. I'm trying to do it by using a `for` loop but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error : Couldn't process parameters
```

Can anyone provide me with any suggestions on this?

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```py
user_details = {}
create_user_ID = input(" Enter the user ID :  ")
user_details[create_user_ID] = {}
user_name = input(" Enter the user name : ")
user_details[create_user_ID]['Name'] = user_name
user_age = int(input(" Enter the Age : "))
user_details[create_user_ID]['Age'] = user_age

for v in user_details.values():
    cols = v.keys()
    vals = v.values()

    sql = "INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
        ', '.join(cols),
        ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));

    cursor.execute(sql, vals)
```

Comment: Fix spelling, improve readability, remove unnecessary closing.

Comment: Improve wording

Comment: Just place val instead of (val,)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python nested dictionary with SQL insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002162/python-nested-dictionary-with-sql-insert)

Comment: Please don't edit your questions by overwriting the original text @Vishal MuraliKrishnan, it makes very difficult to follow the problem and keep track of what you're tried or not. It's much better if you add the additional information under some EDIT heading at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your problem is at the last line, when you try to do `cursor.execute(sql,(val,))`.

In Python 3 [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) and [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) doesn't return lists, but some dictionary view objects wrapping the data, so what you're getting from `(val,)` is a single value tuple with one `dict_values` object.

Try using just `val` as @niteshbisht suggested or `list(val)` or `tuple(val)` if that still doesn't work.

Please see also [Python nested dictionary with SQL insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002162/python-nested-dictionary-with-sql-insert), as it looks like you're trying to address the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Eduardo, I think I have made some mistake in creating new table in SQL by  mentioning its column also. Could you please review the code let me know your thoughts on this

Comment: And I've edited the for loop based on your suggestion also still also I'm not getting the answer. Error : Couldn't process parameters.                                                                            Thank you for your time in advance

Comment: I have updated the query, Could you please review the code and let me know your thoughts !!

Comment: I've tried the new code you posted @Vishal MuraliKrishnan and it works for me on Python 3.7 using `cursor.execute(sql, list(vals))` or `cursor.execute(sql, tuple(vals))` instead of `cursor.execute(sql, vals)`

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, Thank you soo much, Code is getting excuted without any issues

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T** use the most obvious one (%s with %) in real code, it's open to attacks.

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO Details ? Values ?" ,(col, placeholders))
cursor.execute(sql,val)
```